# Variable name collision in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am attempting to compute a moving median on a variable contained within a data.frame using dplyr.   The problem I am running into is that the function that I am passing into rollapply() has the same name as a variable in the original data.frame.  For example:

```
df <- data.frame(median = seq(1:100))

df %>%
  mutate(ln_median = log(median)) %>%
  mutate(ln_median_10 = rollapply(ln_median, 5, median))
```

Generates the error message:

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
>     '1:100' is not a function, character or symbol

The underlying cause is that the median in the rollapply() is resolving to the variable in the data.frame and not the function "median".   I have been able to get around this with the following code:

```
df %>% mutate(ln_median = log(median)) %>%
       mutate(ln_median_10 = rollapply(ln_median, 5, function(a) median(a), fill = NA))
```

That is, by wrapping the median function in order to suppress it from being interpreted as a variable within the data.frame.

Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: I copied your code and got a different error:  "Column `ln_median_10` must be length 100 (the number of rows) or one, not 96".  I fixed by adding the `fill = NA` parameter to `rollapply`

Comment: Which package is `rollapply` from? is it `zoo`?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to pass the function name in as

```
stats::median
```

Answer (score 0):

As @lebelinoz mentioned in the comments, you can use `fill = NA` to solve the unequal length error. Not able to reproduce your error though. Also note that `mutate` allows you to use a variable you have just created within the same function. So no need for the second `mutate`:

```
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(ln_median = log(median),
         ln_median_10 = rollapply(ln_median, 5, median, fill = NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was really the issue (but I can't reproduce it either), you could use `match.fun("median")` instead of `median`